# Extracting and Parsing the WWW-Authenticate header from HttpResponseMessage in .NET

Tags: .net, http, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm building an app using Azure AD to call the Microsoft Graph.  In certain requests that require elevated access, the graph is issuing an HTTP 403 error with a special `claims` parameter inside the `WWW-Authenticate` header I need to use in a subsequent request.

In .NET, how can I extract the [WWW-Authenticate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#page-7) header produced by an API in response to a Forbidden (HTTP 403) from the `HttpResponseMessage` class?

Moreover, what's the best way to parse this header to extract out certain pieces of data? For instance, the response is comma separated, but also contains commas inside the chunk of data I need.

Comment: You can access it in the `Headers` property `response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate`

Comment: Show a [mcve]  of what is to be parsed. and the desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to extract the parameter, you can use the following code to extract the `WWW-Authenticate` header:

```
HttpResponseMessage graphResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
graphResponse.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.ToString();
```

This will provide the entire header. Not to extract the claims parameter, you can parse the `WWW-Authenticate` header by `,` and a space after.  The RFC for HTTP does not give clear guidance so it's based on the individual service. For this particular error, it splitting by a comma and space or by looking for `claims` is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it in the `Headers` property `response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate`

From there you can traverse the values. The standard is already handled in the code. You would only need to manage the custom details specific to your system.

```
if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden) {
    var wwwAuthenticate = response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate;
    foreach (var auth in wwwAuthenticate) {
        var scheme = auth.Scheme;
        var parameter = auth.Parameter;
        //Handle the data as needed
    }
}
```

Quoting comments found in  [AuthenticationHeaderValue.cs source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Headers/AuthenticationHeaderValue.cs#L19) for the `Parameter` property

```
// We simplify parameters by just considering them one string. The caller is responsible for correctly parsing
// the string.
// The reason is that we can't determine the format of parameters. According to Errata 1959 in RFC 2617 
// parameters can be "token", "quoted-string", or "#auth-param" where "auth-param" is defined as 
// "token "=" ( token | quoted-string )". E.g. take the following BASIC example:
// Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
// Due to Base64 encoding we have two final "=". The value is neither a token nor a quoted-string, so it must
// be an auth-param according to the RFC definition. But that's also incorrect: auth-param means that we 
// consider the value before the first "=" as "name" and the final "=" as "value".
```

Comment: Ah cool, I tried manually splitting the field but this looks cleaner. Let me try it out.