# Parse WwwAuthenticate challenge string

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am working on a client for a RESTful service, using .NET Core 2.0. The remote service returns challenges like this:

```
WwwAuthenticate: Bearer realm="https://somesite/auth",service="some site",scope="some scope"
```

Which need to get turned into token requests like:

```
GET https://somesite/auth?service=some%20site&scope=some%20scope
```

Parsing the header to get a scheme and parameter is easy with `AuthenticationHeaderValue`, but that just gets me the `realm="https://somesite/auth",service="some site",scope="some scope"` string. How can I easily and reliably parse this to the individual `realm`, `service`, and `scope` components? It's not quite JSON, so deserializing it with NewtonSoft `JsonConvert` won't work. I could regex it into something that looks like XML or JSON, but that seems incredibly hacky (not to mention unreliable).

Surely there's a better way?

Comment: `String.Split`, `Regex.Matches` I don't see a better built-in way..

Comment: It gets a little tricky because `scope` can (and often does) contain commas, so just splitting on `,` won't work.

Comment: So regex is your friend :)

Comment: I wouldn't say that. But we can come to an understanding if we have to.

Comment: I wonder why you want to reinvent the wheels, http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/apis.html?highlight=bearer

Comment: I don't, @LexLi. Are you saying `IdentityServer` components can parse a challenge string like this? If they can that would be perfect, but I'm not seeing that from the doc you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't see a non-hacky  way. Maybe this *hacky* way may help

```
string input = @"WwwAuthenticate: Bearer realm=""https://somesite/auth"",service=""some site"",scope=""some, scope""";
var dict = Regex.Matches(input, @"[\W]+(\w+)=""(.+?)""").Cast<Match>()
          .ToDictionary(x => x.Groups[1].Value, x => x.Groups[2].Value);

var url = dict["realm"] + "?" + string.Join("&", dict.Where(x => x.Key != "realm").Select(x => x.Key + "=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(x.Value)));
```

**OUTPUT**

`url => https://somesite/auth?service=some+site&scope=some%2C+scope`

*BTW: I added a `,` in "scope"*

Comment: I had to make it `@"[\W]*(\w+)=""(.+?)"""` to catch the `realm` when using `header.Parameter`, but it does work. I'm going to leave this open for a bit on the off chance somebody has a cleaner solution, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Possible duplicate of [How to parse values from Www-Authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48452636/how-to-parse-values-from-www-authenticate/57263137)

Using the schema defined in [RFC6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-3) and [RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html), a slightly more precise parser implementation is included below. This parser takes into account the possibility that strings might contain `=`, `,`, and/or escaped `"`.

```cs
internal class AuthParamParser
{
  private string _buffer;
  private int _i;

  private AuthParamParser(string param)
  {
    _buffer = param;
    _i = 0;
  }

  public static Dictionary<string, string> Parse(string param)
  {
    var state = new AuthParamParser(param);
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var token = state.ReadToken();
    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
      if (!state.ReadDelim('='))
        return result;
      result.Add(token, state.ReadString());
      if (!state.ReadDelim(','))
        return result;
      token = state.ReadToken();
    }
    return result;
  }

  private string ReadToken()
  {
    var start = _i;
    while (_i < _buffer.Length && ValidTokenChar(_buffer[_i]))
      _i++;
    return _buffer.Substring(start, _i - start);
  }

  private bool ReadDelim(char ch)
  {
    while (_i < _buffer.Length && char.IsWhiteSpace(_buffer[_i]))
      _i++;
    if (_i >= _buffer.Length || _buffer[_i] != ch)
      return false;
    _i++;
    while (_i < _buffer.Length && char.IsWhiteSpace(_buffer[_i]))
      _i++;
    return true;
  }

  private string ReadString()
  {
    if (_i < _buffer.Length && _buffer[_i] == '"')
    {
      var buffer = new StringBuilder();
      _i++;
      while (_i < _buffer.Length)
      {
        if (_buffer[_i] == '\\' && (_i + 1) < _buffer.Length)
        {
          _i++;
          buffer.Append(_buffer[_i]);
          _i++;
        }
        else if (_buffer[_i] == '"')
        {
          _i++;
          return buffer.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
          buffer.Append(_buffer[_i]);
          _i++;
        }
      }
      return buffer.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
      return ReadToken();
    }
  }

  private bool ValidTokenChar(char ch)
  {
    if (ch < 32)
      return false;
    if (ch == '(' || ch == ')' || ch == '<' || ch == '>' || ch == '@'
      || ch == ',' || ch == ';' || ch == ':' || ch == '\\' || ch == '"'
      || ch == '/' || ch == '[' || ch == ']' || ch == '?' || ch == '='
      || ch == '{' || ch == '}' || ch == 127 || ch == ' ' || ch == '\t')
      return false;
    return true;
  }
}
```